# ¿Cómo abrir mi chat hecho en socket.io desde otra pc en mi misma red con XAMPP?

Tags: javascript, html, html5, nodejs, socket.io

Quisiera probar que funciona correctamente mi chat sacado de la documentación oficial de socket.io

> https://socket.io/docs/

Todo va bien, pude hacer cada cosa que especifica la librería para enviar y recibir mensajes, pero cuando intento entrar desde otra PC conectada a mi misma red me marca que no existe.

En mi computadora principal en donde está corriendo XAMPP tengo la IP 192.168.0.4 Incluso, especifiqué las rutas como http://192.168.0.4:3000 (3000 es el puerto que estoy usando para abrir el websocket).

Cuando intento entrar a http://192.168.0.4:3000 desde otra computadora conectada a la misma red me marca que no existe, sin embargo sí puedo entrar al directorio principal de XAMPP desde esta otra PC pero no logro entrar al chat que hice dentro de mi directorio el cual está dentro de `xampp/htdocs/socket`, ya que si entro a este apartado desde mi otra PC no funciona el chat.

Intenté asimismo abrir el puerto en mi router pero sigo sin tener éxito. Dejo mi código:

index.js

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');
  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log('user disconnected');
  });
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    console.log('message: ' + msg);
     io.emit('chat message', msg);
  });
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Socket.IO chat</title>
    <style>
      * { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
      body { font: 13px Helvetica, Arial; }
      form { background: #000; padding: 3px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
      form input { border: 0; padding: 10px; width: 90%; margin-right: .5%; }
      form button { width: 9%; background: rgb(130, 224, 255); border: none; padding: 10px; }
      #messages { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #messages li { padding: 5px 10px; }
      #messages li:nth-child(odd) { background: #eee; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form action="">
      <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
    </form>
    <script src="http://192.168.0.4:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function () {
        var socket = io("http://192.168.0.4:3000");
        $('form').submit(function(e){
          e.preventDefault(); // prevents page reloading
          console.log($('#m').val());
          socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
          $('#m').val('');
          return false;
        });
        socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
          $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

He solucionado mi problema, la solución fue (puede sonar muy de novato, pero a veces pasa) desactivar el Firewall de Windows. Gracias.

Comment: Y por qué no mejor crear una regla de entrada o salida para el servicio en cuestión, ya que esto deja a la computadora vulberable

Comment: tu antivirus podria detectar esa conexion y bloquearla tambien

Comment: @alfap Gracias por sus sugerencias, haré eso ya que sí, tienes razón, deja vulnerable a la computadora.